# Проект под названием " Давайте говорить как Петербуржцы"

Tags: стилистика

Недавно в Интернете наткнулся на проект под названием "Давайте говорить как Петербуржцы". Проект, на мой взгляд, не плохой, но вот автор проекта, филолог Наталья Романова,то ли Л. Вебицкая, все же немного загибают палку. Как авторитетные филологи( кандидаты наук, доктора) могут призывать людей говорить так?!Например: вместо "топлесс",простите за выражение, " титьки наружу". Какая -то издевка. На этом странности не заканчиваются. Автор предлагает говорить ***кура*** вместо ***курица***( при этом утверждает(!!!!)что курица , заметье(!!!) неправильно)!!!! Бред!!!! Дальше - больше! Автор приводит ряд устойчивых выражений, которые вряд ли встретишь в живом разговорном языке. Вот некоторые из них: Паче чаяния - сверх ожидания, неожиданно;ничтоже сумняшеся - не сомневаюсь, не раздумываю; и иже с ним ( с ними) - и ему(им) подобные. (Т.е.авторы призывают говорить именно этими выражениями). Но и это еще не все. Есть еще слова неприличные ( не уверен,это монтаж или на самом деле это правда. Поищите в интернете, найдете!)Слова достаточно неприличны, поэтому здесь не хочу писать. А что вы думаете по этому поводу?

[image]

Comment: Судя по примерам, это фейк)

Comment: Безусловно, фейк. На самом деле это серьезный проект СПбГУ совместно с Советом по культуре речи при губернаторе Санкт-Петербурга.

Я уже задавала [вопрос][1] об этом проекте. Прошу высказываться.


  [1]: http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/21196/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B6%D1%86%D1%8B

Comment: Дерзкий Grantum, ну а другой стороны, в чем тогда суть проекта? Зачем он называется " Давайте говорить как Петербуржцы". Назвали бы тогда " Давайте говорить правильно".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ссылочку дайте.
Мне попадалось что-то такое, всерьез не принял. 
Но там, про "титьки" кажется не было.

Но если без этих заморочек, то в принципе петербуржское произношение заслуживает внимания и уважения вполне серьезных филологов.

Comment: В Яндексе набираем " Давайте говорить как Петербуржцы" - и, о чудо! - такое принесет! ( я имею в виду плакаты).